# Authorize attributes and roles

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

so I am setting up a identity framework. I assign a role to a user after creating it with usermanager like so:

```
var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>());

if(!await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("admin"))
    await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("admin"));

var userToAddRole = _userManager.FindByName(userModel.UserName);
_userManager.AddToRole(userToAddRole.Id, "admin");
//_userManager.AddClaim(userToAddRole.Id, new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "admin"));
await _userManager.UpdateAsync(userToAddRole);
```

All database tables like AspNetRoles AspNetUserRoles updates correctly. But when I try to access

```
[Authorize (Roles = "admin")]
[Route("changepassword")]
```

the 401 error unauthorized always follows. Without the (Roles = "admin") it works fine. I am using OAuth bearer token authorization if that matters.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Yes, I am currently assigning the role when creating a new user. After that I use username and password to login (generate the token).

Comment: Can You show how You create token?

Comment: @BeginnerSirius, did u add Claim to user's token while authenticating?

Comment: No, I did not. Can you give an example? If I do something like             identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "admin")); then all authenticated users will be admins, no?